# How to take ID of a row in gridview when you press a button in a row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="IDProject" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Vertical" style="margin-top:2rem" Width="1056px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="ProjectLeader" HeaderText="Project Leader">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("ProjectLeader") %>' ID="lvProjectLeader"  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" SortExpression="ProjectName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start date:" SortExpression="StartDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>' ID="lbStartDate" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client Name" SortExpression="Client name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Client name") %>' ID="lbClientName" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employees">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button Text="Open" ID="EmployeesOpen" OnClick="EmployeesOpen_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline-primary" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    InsertCommand="Insert into Project values(@ProjectName, @ClientID,@ProjectLeader,@StartDate)" 
    SelectCommand="select IDProject, ProjectLeader, ProjectName, StartDate, ClientID, Client.Name from Project inner join Client on IDClient = ClientID"
    UpdateCommand="Update Project set ProjectName = @ProjectName where IDProject = @IDProject">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectLeader" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="IDProject" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I made a gridview table for Projects which has values ProjectName, ClientID, ProjectLeader, StartDate and all the employees that work on that Project. Since i cant fit all the employees that work on a single project inside a small table i made a button inside that column that redirects you to another page where you can see table with all the employees. The employees are in another table in sql and i made third table which connects Projects and employees and it only contains ProjectID and EmployeeID. I have a button inside every row but i cant find a way how to make in code behind so that it takes the id of that project and prints on another page only employees that are working on that project.

```
public partial class Project : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void EmployeesOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Employees_On_Project.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find what you are looking for here : https://forums.asp.net/t/1957409.aspx?Gridview+get+SelectedRow+in+button+click+event